# How do I upcast a collection of base class in C#?

Tags: c#

In C#, I have a class A that I cannot modify. From this class I've created class B (i.e. inherited from A) which adds some properties. I also have a static function that returns List`<A>` when GetListOfA() is called.

How can I cast the return from GetListOfA() to List`<B>`?

e.g. List`<B>` bList = foo.GetListOfA() as List`<B>`

Comment: Also note that even if you were trying to go backwards, just because B inherits from A does not mean that List<B> inherits from List<A>. This is called covariance and will have limited support in the next version of C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using C# 3.0 (Visual Studio 2008), you can:

```
using System.Linq;

List<B> bList = foo.GetListOfA().Cast<B>().ToList();
```

Comment: Not sure if using types from `System.Linq` requires the C# 3.0 compiler.  I think using .NET 3.5 should suffice.

Comment: The `System.Linq` namespace is located in v3.x of the `System.Core` assembly, which can't be used with C# 2.0.

Comment: At least, Visual Studio 2005 won't let you target it. You might be able to use the commandline compiler--I've never tried. Anyway, you'd be missing out on the ability to chain extension methods... etc etc.

Comment: The 3.0 compiler was released with .NET 3.5 and is critical to allow the extenson method syntax as used above.  There are ways to use some bits of Linq but still be able to run without requiring more than .NET 2.0 on a machine (look around here).

Answer (score 5):

Using System.Linq, you can say

```
List<B> bList = foo.GetListOfA().Cast<B>().ToList()
```

Or

```
var bs = foo.GetListOfA().Cast<B>()
```

Or

```
static class AExts
{
    public List<B> AsB( this List<A> list )
    {
        return list.Cast<B>().ToList();
    }
}

List<B> bList = foo.GetListOfA().AsB();
```

Or

```
static class FooExts
{
    public List<B> AsB( this Foo foo )
    {
        return list.GetListOfA().AsB();
    }
}
List<B> bList = foo.AsB();
```

Or if you dont have/ cant /wont use Linq, algorithms in PowerCollections has the same thing

And I didnt look at the other answer even though it probably says the same!

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You must actually create a new `List<B>` and add all the items from the original list to the new list.

The easiest way to do this, apart from writing your own method to do so, is to use Linq (see other answers).

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done the following way using linq

```
List<A> listOfA;
List<B> listOfB = listOfA.Select(a => a as B).ToList();
```