# Check if Object is Dictionary or List

Tags: c#, json, generics, mono

Working with .NET 2 in mono, I'm using a basic `JSON` library that returns nested string, object Dictionary and lists.

I'm writing a mapper to map this to a jsonData class that I already have and I need to be able to determine if the underlying type of an `object` is a Dictionary or a List. Below is the method I'm using to perform this test, but was wondering if theres a cleaner way?

```
private static bool IsDictionary(object o) {
    try {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)o;
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}

private static bool IsList(object o) {
    try {
        List<object> list = (List<object>)o;
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The library I'm using is `litJson` but the `JsonMapper` class essentially doesn't work on iOS, hence the reason I am writing my own mapper.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use the `is` keyword and reflection.

```
public bool IsList(object o)
{
    if(o == null) return false;
    return o is IList &&
           o.GetType().IsGenericType &&
           o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<>));
}

public bool IsDictionary(object o)
{
    if(o == null) return false;
    return o is IDictionary &&
           o.GetType().IsGenericType &&
           o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Dictionary<,>));
}
```

Comment: system.Type doesnt seem to be available to me in mono and so cant use GetGenericTypeDefinition.. is that bit necessary?

Comment: It looks like the types are always `List<object>` and `Dictionary<string, object>`, so you don't need all this reflection.

Comment: o can be a string, int, long, bool, double, List or Dictionary

Comment: @user1711383 You can just use the `is` keyword if you are certain of the generic type parameters. e.g. `o is Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: And you can use [`(value as IEnumerable<object>).Cast<object>().ToList()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16147909/1366033) if you want to cast the object into a usable type

Comment: When I do "os is IList" it gives me an error: "CS0305: Using the generic type 'IList<T>' requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: @shieldgenerator7 you need to use the non-Generic interface `IList`  which is in the System.Collections namespace.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to check that a certain object is of some type, use the `is` operator. For example:

```
private static bool IsDictionary(object o)
{
    return o is Dictionary<string, object>;
}
```

Though for something this simple, you probably don't need a separate method, just use the `is` operator directly where you need it.

Comment: Careful - the `is` operator checks to see if the left hand object is COMPATIBLE with the right hand object, NOT if some object is necessarily the exact same type...

Comment: @Ben Yes, but if the type of `o` inherits from `Dictionary<string, object>`, I think `true` is the right answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the above answer.  In order to use `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` you must preface the method with `GetType()`.  If you look at MSDN this is how `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` is accessed:

```
public virtual Type GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

Here is the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public bool IsList(object o)
{
    return o is IList &&
       o.GetType().IsGenericType &&
       o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<>));
}

public bool IsDictionary(object o)
{
    return o is IDictionary &&
       o.GetType().IsGenericType &&
       o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Dictionary<>));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to detect the object is `List/Dictionary` or not, you can use `myObject.GetType().IsGenericType && myObject is IEnumerable`

Here is some example:

```
var lst = new List<string>();
var dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
string s = "Hello!";
object obj1 = new { Id = 10 };
object obj2 = null;

// True
Console.Write(lst.GetType().IsGenericType && lst is IEnumerable);
// True
Console.Write(dic.GetType().IsGenericType && dic is IEnumerable);
// False
Console.Write(s.GetType().IsGenericType && s is IEnumerable);
// False
Console.Write(obj1.GetType().IsGenericType && obj1 is IEnumerable);
// NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of 
// an object, so you need to check for null cases too
Console.Write(obj2.GetType().IsGenericType && obj2 is IEnumerable);
```

Comment: error CS0305: Using the generic type 'IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: I didn't mention `IEnumerable<T>`, please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = obj.GetType();

if(t.IsGenericType && typeof(System.Collections.IList).IsAssignableFrom(t))
{
    // it is of type list

    // if its a list of integers for example then listOf will be of type int
    var listOf = t.GenericTypeArguments[0];
}
```