# Casting an object to a IList with an abstract type parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In my code, I have an object:

```
object obj = ...
```

Which I know is of type MyListType, where MyListType is a subclass of IList and T is a subclass of MyAbstractClass. The type parameter of MyListType is constrained so that it is always a subclass of MyAbstractClass.

However, trying to cast obj

```
MyListType<MyAbstractClass> myList = (MyListType<MyAbstractClass>)obj;
```

gives a runtime error.

I tried to define an explicit operator

```
public static explicit operator MyListType<MyAbstractClass>(MyListType<T> list)
{
    MyListType<MyAbstractClass> newList = new MyListType<MyAbstractClass>();
    foreach(T t in list)
        newList.Add((MyAbstractClass) t);
    return newList;
}
```

However, this operator doesn't get used by the cast since obj is an object, not a MyListType. Is there a workaround to successfully perform this cast?

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837063/cast-object-to-generic-list), but their the list was of an unknown type.

Comment: If `MyListType<MyAbstractClass> myList = (MyListType<MyAbstractClass>)obj;` gives a runtime error then `obj` is NOT of the type you think it is!

Comment: Could you please edit your question and paste the class definitions?

Comment: Classes (and `IList<T>`) are invariant so a `MyList<Subclass>` is not an instance of `MyList<MyAbstractClass>`. You can cast it to an `IEnumerable<MyAbstractClass>` though.

Comment: Have you tried `Convert.ChangeType(obj,typeof(MyListType<MyAbstractClass>))`?

Comment: @Lee That works! I've added it as an answer to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reworking my code so that I wouldn't have to do this, but the solution is to first cast it to an IEnumerable, and then add the IEnumerable to a list.

```
MyListType<MyAbstractClass> list = new MyListType<MyAbstractClass>();
IEnumerable<MyAbstractClass> enumerable = obj as IEnumerable<MyAbstractClass>;
list.AddRange(enumerable);
```

Comment: Or more simply: `var list = ((IEnumerable<MyAbstractClass>) obj).ToList();`