# Convert package variable of type System.Object to a List<String> with SSIS C# Script task

Tags: c#, ssis, casting, etl, script-task

I am using the following code:

```
Object duplicateDevices = Dts.Variables["User::DuplicateDevices"].Value;
        List<DuplicateDeviceModel> lstduplicateDevices = (List<DuplicateDeviceModel>)duplicateDevices;
```

`User::DuplicateDevices` is declared as object in the variable but in the script task while typecasting im getting the type casting error; I wanted it to be converted into `List<DuplicateDeviceModel>`

Comment: Is the variable initialized before entering this script?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to `IEnumerable` using the following syntax:

```
IEnumerable lstduplicateDevices = duplicateDevices as IEnumerable;
```

If it works you can specify the ` using the following syntax:

```
IEnumerable<DuplicateDeviceModel> ieDDM = lstduplicateDevices.OfType<DuplicateDeviceModel>();
```

**Reference**

- [Cast Object to Generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837063/cast-object-to-generic-list)

Answer (score 0):

In the script, try first filling a data table from the `DuplicateDevices` object variable.  After this, populate the list of type `DuplicateDeviceModel` with the data table.  Without knowing the columns or data types you're working with the following is a general example, and the columns as well as their data types will need to be adjusted according to those that you're using.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;


        List<DuplicateDeviceModel> lstduplicateDevices = new List<DuplicateDeviceModel>();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adapter.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::DuplicateDevices"].Value);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
           {
            //convert columns from data type to data types of list as necessary
            lstduplicateDevices.Add(new DuplicateDeviceModel() { 
            ColumnA = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
            ColumnB = dr[1].ToString() });
            }
```