# Convert object to List<int>

Tags: c#

I have stored List of int in a object type and I am trying to convert object to List of int using below code. Every time, it throws a casting exception.

```cs
List<int> ObjToList(object array)
{
    try
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        var enumerator = ((IEnumerable)array).GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            list.Add(enumerator.Current);
        }
        var val = list.Cast<int>().ToList();
        return val;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in the array? What's the exact error?

Comment: please include the code that calls the method...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast Object to Generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837063/cast-object-to-generic-list)

Comment: If you have a `List<int>` already, can't you just cast? Please provide more context in terms of how you're calling this.

Comment: List @John Skeet said, just cast it: `object ints = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
                List<int> result = (List<int>)ints;`

Comment: Array is

List<int> val=new List<int>{1,2,3,4}
object obj=val;

Answer (score 3):

Some sort of universal converter with pattern matching.
Just for fun:

```
static List<T> ObjToList<T>(object obj)
{
    switch (obj)
    {
        case List<T> list:
            // we passed a list, so just return it as is
            return list;

        case IEnumerable<T> genericEnumerable:
            // we passed a generic sequence, and items type is what we need
            return genericEnumerable.ToList();

        case IEnumerable enumerable:
            // we passed some sequence, and we don't know, what is the type of any particular item;
            // using OfType<T> instead of Cast<T> allows to pass sequences that
            // contain items with different types
            return enumerable.OfType<T>().ToList();

        default:
            // we passed none of above;
            // just return empty list
            return new List<T>(0);
    }
}
```

Samples:

```
// displays 3
Console.WriteLine(ObjToList<int>(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }).Count);
// displays 3 
Console.WriteLine(ObjToList<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }).Count);
// displays 2, one item is not an integer
Console.WriteLine(ObjToList<int>(new ArrayList { 1, "2", 3 }).Count); 
// displays 0, all items are characters, but not integers
Console.WriteLine(ObjToList<int>("123").Count); 
// displays 0, not a sequence at all
Console.WriteLine(ObjToList<int>(123).Count); 
// displays 0, not a sequence at all
Console.WriteLine(ObjToList<int>(null).Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var array = new int[2] { 1, 2 };

//convert the array to object (for testing purpose)
object arrayasobject = array; 

//check whether the object is int[]
if (arrayasobject.GetType() == typeof(int[]))
{
     //approach #1 .. cast to List<int>
     var list1 = new List<int>(arrayasobject as int[]);

     //approach #2 .. using LINQ
     var list2 = (arrayasobject as int[]).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The OP's `array` parameter is of type `object`, not `int[]`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the post to reflect object

Comment: So now you've got code that will fail unless the OP *actually* has an `int[]` in their `array` parameter, and there's no indication that that's the case.

Comment: @JonSkeet have added a condition to check before cast

Comment: But the method still doesn't do anything *useful* if the value doesn't happen to be an `int[]`. Sure, you avoid an exception... but this is still a long-winded way of *only* handling the `int[]` case.

Comment: For example, here's a shorter way of achieving the same thing, but returning an empty list if it's not an `int[]`: `return (array as int[])?.ToList() ?? new List<int>();`. But I wouldn't add that as an answer, as it only handles the single case which isn't even mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question

```
List<int> ObjToList(object array)
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    if (array is IEnumerable<int> valueSet)
    {
        result.AddRange(valueSet);
    }
    return result;
}
```

However not sure why you would like to do this, as mentioned in the comments, what's the object when you call it.

Comment: Array is List<int> val=new List<int>{1,2,3,4} 
object obj = val;

Comment: @Manohar, than why bother with the method, you have a list of int already?