# How to derive a list of Parent type elements from a list of Child type elements?

Tags: c#, list, parent-child

I've been searching for quite some time without success how to derive a list of Parent type elements from a list of Child type elements. 
The Parent type contains persistent data, and the Child type adds some transient data that I don't need later on.

I would therefore like to keep the properties of the Parent type only and drop the additional properties of Child type, like on the following example:

```
public class MainPage
{

    public class Parent
    {
        public string ParentProperty;
    }
    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public string ChildProperty;
    }

    public static List<Child> listChild = new List<Child> {
        new Child { ParentProperty = "ABC", ChildProperty = "XYZ"},
        new Child { ParentProperty = "DEF", ChildProperty = "UVW"}
    };

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        List<Parent> listParent = GetParentList(listChild);

        //listParent should contain 2 elements, each with only 1 property containing "ABC" and "DEF" respectively...
    }

    public List<Parent> GetParentList(List<Child> listchild)
    {
        return listchild.????????; //what should I include here ???
    }
}
```

All my tries like `return (listchild as List<Parent>);` give me Child elements in my List, i.e. with ChildProperty "XYZ" and "UVW", which make the rest of my code fail...

Thanks for your ideas !

Comment: `return listchild.Cast<Parent>().ToList()` btw you **dont** drop any Child property in this way... they still exist and you can cast them back to Child...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1266056/4767498

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a representation of your child instances as Parent references:

```
public List<Parent> GetParentList(List<Child> listchild)
{
    return listchild.Cast<Parent>().ToList();
}
```

If you *really* want to have Parent instances with the same data as the childs, you will have to create new instances and copy over your data:

```
public List<Parent> GetParentList(List<Child> listchild)
{
    return listchild.Select(child => new Parent{ ParentProperty = child.ParentProperty }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Your first suggestion does compile right, but as soon as I want to use the `List<Parent>` for instance in a Serializer, I get an error as it finds the ChildProperty, which is not known in the Parent definition.

Comment: I like your 2nd suggestion :-) Is there an easy way to copy all the Parent properties at once, or do I really need to list them all one by one ?

Comment: @Daniel you seem to have an XY Problem. Maybe you should ask about your *problem* instead of your perceived *solution*. Do you want to serialize your child class as parent class?

Comment: The Serialization is one of the challenges, yes, as it must happen in the parent class (which is shared between several projects, and only one of the projects has knowledge of the child class). Hence my need to strip off the child properties. If you know of some articles I could read about the subject, I would be pleased to get that info. Cheers